# How to add to pythonpath in virtualenvironment

Tags: python, virtualenv

On my windows machine I created a virtual environement in conda where I run   python 3.6. I want to permanently add a folder to the virtual python path environment. If I append something to `sys.path` it is lost on exiting python.

Outside of my virtual enviroment I can just add to user variables by going to advanced system settings. I have no idea how to do this within my virtual enviroment.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why not just make a `virtualenv` with the up to date version, which would be the proper way to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I can just add to user variables" just means adding an environment variable to the command shell. Virtualenv shouldn't (by default at least) clear environment variables. So it should just work if you already have `PYTHONPATH` set.

If you only want the path available to the virtualenv then modify the file called `Scripts/activate.bat` in the virtualenv folder and add the line:

```
set PYTHONPATH=path/to/dir
```

Comment: Thanks. So I made the venv using conda. There are some modules in the venv which I need. I don't want to add these on my pythonpath outside the venv. When I read the activate.bat I see this: `set "PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\__VENV_BIN_NAME__;%PATH%"` I am not sure what it says. Could you help me translate? How would I add a single dir to this.

Comment: The setting of `PATH` is not relevant to your issue. That's about making sure when in your virtualenv, that the virtualenv python is used instead any other version of python on your system. All you need to do is add `set "PYTHONPATH=path/to/dir"` after that line where `path/to/dir` is the full path to location of the modules you want to use.

Answer (score -2):

If you are on Windows 10+, this should work:
1) Click on the Windows button on the screen or on the keyboard, both in the bottom left section.

2) Type "Environment Variables" (without the quotation marks, of course).

3) Click on the option that says something like "Edit the System Environment Variables"

4) Click on the "Advanced Tab," and then click "Environment Variables" (Near the bottom)

5) Click "Path" in the top box - it should be the 3rd option - and then click "Edit" (the top one)

6) Click "New" at the top, and then add the path to the folder you want to create.

7) Click "Ok" at the bottom of all the pages that were opened as a result of the above-described actions to save.

That should work, please let me know in the comments if it doesn't.

Comment: This might only work for folders created in the real environment but should work in the virtual one as well.